# Varchar Encoding in MySQL

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, sql-types

I am coming to MySQL from MS SQL. It was my understanding that in order to store International Characters, I need to declare a field as varchar with UTF-8 character set.

I am using Sequel Pro to develop MySQL database. When I manually enter international characters into a field in my table, it does not understand it and turns it into questions marks (?????).

Could someone please point me into the right direction?

Comment: Try the solution I provided, if it does not work then you have an issue with Sequel Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example,

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-conversion.html

Comment: Thanks. Still not working. I am thinking it could be some issue with Sequel Pro that I am not aware of.

Comment: I would ensure that you have DDL access to that table. Also if you have access to the database through MySQL Command Line I would use that to perform the recommended statement.